# How to replace value in middle of varchar2 column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar2 column with value as - '20210103 20110109' which I want to change 2011 as 2022 that looks like '20210103 20220109'

Answer (score 2):

The way you put it, it is just a simple `replace`:

```
SQL> select replace('20210103 20110109', '2011', '2022') result from dual;

RESULT
-----------------
20210103 20220109

SQL>
```

Could be more complicated if there were other `2011` substrings involved (but that's not what you said).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display different data then, if you only want to change the single value then you can use:

```sql
CASE column_name
WHEN '20210103 20110109'
THEN '20210103 20220109'
ELSE column_name
END
```

If you want to display all `2011` values in that substring as `2022` then you can use:

```sql
CASE
WHEN SUBSTR(column_name, 10, 4) = '2011'
THEN SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 9) || '2022' || SUBSTR(column_name, 14)
ELSE column_name
END
```

---

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name) AS
SELECT '20210103 20110109' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20210103 20120109' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20210103 20130109' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20210103 20140109' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20212011 20112011' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT column_name,
       CASE column_name
       WHEN '20210103 20110109'
       THEN '20210103 20220109'
       ELSE column_name
       END AS replacement1,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(column_name, 10, 4) = '2011'
       THEN SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 9) || '2022' || SUBSTR(column_name, 14)
       ELSE column_name
       END AS replacement2
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> | COLUMN_NAME | REPLACEMENT1 | REPLACEMENT2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 20210103 20110109 | 20210103 20220109 | 20210103 20220109 |
> | 20210103 20120109 | 20210103 20120109 | 20210103 20120109 |
> | 20210103 20130109 | 20210103 20130109 | 20210103 20130109 |
> | 20210103 20140109 | 20210103 20140109 | 20210103 20140109 |
> | 20212011 20112011 | 20212011 20112011 | 20212011 20222011 |

---

If you just want to `UPDATE` a single value:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET    column_name = '20210103 20220109'
WHERE  column_name = '20210103 20110109'
```

or, if you want to change all substrings between the 10<sup>th</sup> and 13<sup>th</sup> characters from 2011 to 2022:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET    column_name = SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 9) || '2022' || SUBSTR(column_name, 14)
WHERE  SUBSTR(column_name, 10, 4) = '2011'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94937474307aea8481e81475579ae3a3)*